# Parse JSON string to object with attributes

Tags: ruby, openstruct

Currently my app is parsing JSON in following way:

```
OpenStruct.new(JSON.parse(json_string))
```

but there are problems with this approach:

1. JSON allows root-level arrays like `[{id: 1, name: "first"}, {id: 2, name: "second"}]` and OpenStruct can't handle them throwing an exception.
2. OpenStruct does not handle nested elements.

I found some solutions like RecursiveOpenStruct and others.

1. They handle nested hashes, but still can't handle top-level arrays
2. Hashes nested into array remain hashes: `{data: [{id: 1, name: "first"}, {id: 2, name: "second"}]}` here each `.data[i]` is a Hash.

Comment: What do you expect when you have an array?

Comment: have you looked at https://github.com/intridea/hashie?

Comment: @hakcho: An array of objects. Uri Agassi gave right answer. I will use `Hashie::Mash`.